# SQL Server 2014 DISTINCT with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, distinct, sql-server-2014

Hey all I have the following query that I am trying to get working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    APL.Status
    ,APL.DateModified
    ,APL.PID
    ,APL.PType
    ,APL.PName
    ,APL.PostDate
    ,APL.TID
    ,APL.HRate
    ,APL.Amount
    ,APL.PContact
    ,APL.PMail
    ,APL.PPhone
    ,APL.PFax
    ,APL.RDate
    ,PS.Comments 
FROM 
    [billing].[dbo].[x_APL] AS APL 
INNER JOIN 
    [billing].[dbo].[tblPS] AS PS ON APL.ProjectID = PS.ProjectID 
WHERE 
    APL.PID = '5879'
```

The error that I get is:

> The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

How can I solve this and still use the `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: You should consider changing your datatype to nvarchar now. You could probably use nvarchar(4000) as that is a LOT of information. If the data won't fit there you might have to use nvarchar(max). I have done many in place ddl modifications with no issue. But you should do this in a test environment first of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly, your COMMENTS is ntext, use CAST function to transform the data type into NVARCHAR.

Instead of

```
PS.Comments
```

You can write

```
cast(PS.Comments as nvarchar(4000)) as [Comments]
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks Dance-Henry.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare Ntext,image,text data types...As a workaround try casting all those datatypes to Nvarchar or Varchar..

**Example:**

```
cast(textdatatye as varchar(10))
```

I would recommend replacing them as well since [they will be removed in future version of SQLServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187993.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)..

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: You were close but lacking the **as** like Dance-Henry's example had.